# Quick assignment of Shortcuts: e.g. Preferences?

Tags: shortcut

I know I did it before in 2.80, by clicking some sort of key combination I was able to change the Preferences to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, as it used to be in 2.79.

For the life of me, I can't remember how I did it.

Answer (score 4):

I finally remembered, by right clicking on a menu item one is able to assign the shortcut key :)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit keymap like in 2.79. User settings are renamed into Preferences and moved in Edit menu. (you also can get Preferences in <kbd>F4</kbd> - menu)

[image]